# Edit Joomla 3.x "User Registration" Form Text

Tags: php, joomla, joomla3.0

I am trying to find where I can edit the 'default' text on the User Registration Form for Joomla 3.x website.

The text I am trying to edit is where it says:
**"Don't have an account?".**

I want to add some text after this so it says:
**"Don't have an account? * Please note fees apply to Register"**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you edit core files they can disappear when you update Joomla. To edit this text you should use the Language Overrides feature already within Joomla.

Go to **Extensions** > **Language(s)** and select **Overrides**. Click on **New** in the upper left. On the right hand side you enter the text you are looking for. In your case **Don't have an account?** and click **Search**. Click on the search result that pops up. On the left hand side it will display the text you want to change. Simply change it to whatever you desire and click **Save and Close**.

Now when you update Joomla in the future you don't have to worry about losing your changes. You also have the option to edit or delete the override you have made anytime.

See https://docs.joomla.org/J3.x:Language_Overrides_in_Joomla

Answer (score 1):

To change the link text on the User Registration page, I had to go to {joomla}/language/en-GB/en-GB.com_users.ini